# The sum of the orders of the elements of the group

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G,*)$ a group with the order $p$, where $p$ is a prime number. What is the sum of the orders of the elements of the group?

I know that if $p$ is the order of $G$ then $x^p=e$ but I do not have any other idea.

Comment: This has nothing to do with linear algebra.

Comment: The order of an element in a finite group always divides the order of your group.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** every element has order *equal* to $p$ except the identity. Can you explain why and use this to deduce the sum of the orders of the elements of $G$?

Comment: Yes. thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Let $g\in G$ be nontrivial. Then, by Lagrange's Theorem, the subgroup of $G$ generated by $g$ has order $p$; this equates to saying that the order of $g$ is $p$. But $\lvert G\rvert=p$, so $G=\langle g\rangle$. Also, $g\in G$ was arbitrary (except for the hypothesis that it is nontrivial). This gives $p-1$ elements of order $p$. The order of the identity is $1$. Hence the number you seek is $(p-1)p+1$.